# SonarLint on VSCode doesn't work with self signed SonarQube server

Tags: visual-studio-code, sonarqube, self-signed, sonarlint

We have a SonarQube server which is hosted on a private network which can only be accessible via VPN. URL's something like: https://sonar.internal

Our server is using a Self Signed SSL certificate and it works well on browsers (you may get a warning but can move past it).

However, the issue is that on SonarLint on VSCode, when I try to use **Connected Mode**, I get the following error:

```
Failed: Certificate for <sonar.internal> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.internal, other.internal]
```

However, the certificate's common name has this name already; so it should not even go to alternative names.

I have two questions:

1. How do I find the logs for the SonarLint within VSCode?
2. How do I make it trust the certificate?

PS: I have been on various other posts and there is never anything crystal clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

1. How to enable VSCode Logs for SonarLint?

Go to **VSCode Settings**
Under **Extensions**, expand **SonarLint**
**Enable Sonarlint › Output: Show Verbose Logs**
Restart VSCode

Then, go to **Terminal** and you will see a tab for **Output**
Select **SonarLint** from the dropdown (mine defaults to **Tasks**)

2. How do I make it trust the certificate?

As it turns out, the self signed certificate indeed needed to have the URL into the **Alternative Names**. To me, that doesn't make any sense as the browser's behaviour is to first look at the **Common Name** and then go to **Alternative Names**. But apparently not the case in the VSCode plugin. I created another self-signed SSL certificate with the url into the **Common Name** and **Alternative Names** and viola - works like a charm now.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Given the [RFC-6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.4), the client must not seek into CN if something was found under SAN.